# How to read numeric value containing special Character in Selenium

Tags: java, number-formatting

I want to read numeric value which containing special character (i.e. 8.00%) from the excel sheet.
currently i am trying the code:

```
int fee= (int)txtFee.getNumericCellValue(); 
strFee= String.valueOf(fee);
```

as a result I am getting the value as 0.08, how to deal with such situation.

Comment: 8% is 8 hundredths. What is the issue?